# What is the Functional Difference between Final Fantasy XII and The Zodiac Age?

Tags: version-differences, final-fantasy-12

when i played the original *Final Fantasy XII* (not International with the Zodiac Job System) i remembered that Guests could not be controlled or have their Gambits accessed. this went along side with what Balthier said when Amalia first joined

> Think of her as a Guest. our "Guest" will do as she pleases won't be taking orders from anyone and will leave when she pleases it

And i do recall not being able to issue commands in battle to guests because i never came across their command window when issuing orders.

So this got me thinking, aside from having the Zodiac Job System are there any other functional differences between the original *Final Fantasy XII* and *Final Fantasy XII: The Zodiac Age*?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this site](https://www.polygon.com/2016/7/7/12112604/final-fantasy-12-the-zodiac-age-international-job-system-hd-whats-new), the major differences are:

- Balanced game play

I even experienced this when I played it is that there are alot of baddies who will one-hit-kill you in the earliest stages. They made these areas alot easier for new players.

- Trial mode

Basically, it's a special game mode in the main menu. You fight 100 waves of baddies that get harder and harder with your party.

- High speed mode

It is simply a feature that speeds up gameplay.

Comment: Quest Markers? How do you mean?

Comment: As in it is supposed to help the player to know where their next objective is, I suppose.

Comment: Do you mean while looking on the map, a red X with a circle around it, or the flashing speech bubble with an exclamation mark in it? These both existed in the original game.

Comment: I couldn't find another source for said change, so I will remove it.